# Using curl to load next json page results in php

Tags: php, json, api, curl, pagination

I'm using PHP and cURL to retrieve API information from a website. I have a loop to display all the information on my page which works just fine. The problem I'm having is, my results page displays 10 items per page. The API offers pagination in which it provides me with the next page link url to page 2, 3, and so forth. I cannot find for the life of me, how to make this next link load page 2 information and display it on the same page(it sounds easy enough). I have tried numerous different techniques and none have worked so far. I'm currently stuck where page 1 loads and displays page 1 and 2 data. I would like to have it to where you click the next link and it refreshes the page with your page 2 data and removes page 1 data. Any help is greatly appreciated...Here is my current code...

```
    <section>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" id="searchForm">
                <input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" placeholder="e.g. Haze.." value=""/><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="searchButton" form="searchForm">Search</button>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $url = 'https://www.cannabisreports.com/api/v1.0/strains/search/:' . urlencode ($_POST["searchText"]);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Key : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $jsonobj = json_decode($result);
    echo('<ul id="resultList">');
    foreach($jsonobj->data as $value)
    {

    echo('<li class="resultListItem">');
    echo('<img src="' . $value->image . '">');

    echo '<br>';
    echo $value->seedCompany->name;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value->genetics->names;

    echo '<br>';
    echo $value->reviews->count;
    echo("</li>");
    }
    echo("</ul>");
 //********code for next page 
echo('<a href="index.php?nextPage"> Next </a>');
    if(isset($_GET['nextPage'])) {
        header('location: http://www.strains.blazedmaps.com ');
        $urlNext = $jsonobj->meta->pagination->links->next;
        $curlNext = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($curlNext, CURLOPT_URL, $urlNext);
        curl_setopt ($curlNext, CURLOPT_HTTPheader, array('X-API-Key : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
        curl_setopt ($curlNext, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        $resultNext = curl_exec($curlNext);
        curl_close($curlNext);
        $jsonobjNext = json_decode($resultNext);

        echo('<ul id="resultList">');
    foreach($jsonobjNext->data as $value1)
    {

    echo('<li class="resultListItem">');
    echo('<img src="' . $value1->image . '">');

    echo '<br>';
    echo $value1->seedCompany->name;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $value1->genetics->names;

    echo '<br>';
    echo $value->reviews->count;
    echo("</li>");
    }
    echo("</ul>");
 }

 }



 ?>



   </form>


  </section>
```